# GSON Objects with Annotations vs custom Deserializers

Tags: java, android, performance, gson

Working on a project that has the need to parse multiple MBs of JSON to Java Objects. I have no control over the JSON from the server. But I do know the structure.

But there are a lot of objects that store just 2 values: `id` and `value` where often I only one of those.

To get more concise objects I can see there are at least two ways about it:

1) Recreate the JSON Structure with Java objects and Annotations. Then use that structure to parse to the Data Object I want to use.

2) Parse the JSON with Custom Deserializers to the Data Objects I want to use.

**Is there an other (better) way?**

**What would be the faster way to run, what would be the faster way to program?**

Comment: 1 would be faster and less error-prone as you would transform between (nearly auto-generatable) Java transfer objects and (more useful) Java business objects whilst for 2 the transformation would happen between generic JSON objects and your Java business objects. I personally prefer structural logic over behavioral logic because having two transformations where one is mearly a translation between representations (JSON to transfer objects) and the other one is inside of one problem domain are easier to understand than one bigger transformation combining these two aspects in one.

Comment: What's the problem with creating a pojo with only the fields you need? Gson won't break. It'll parse what you want and you will only have the fields you need. I don't see why you would require the extra complexity of custom serializers or add fields you don't use.